# Why is the throw location not in the backtrace / callstack?

Tags: c++, callstack, backtrace

I am attempting to make post-mortem life a little easier for a very large and cross-platform project that makes use of many 3rd party libraries. On Linux, I use `backtrace()` to dump the backtrace/callstack to console. On Windows, I use `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` to create a minidump and that `StalkWalker` class to dump the callstack to console. Now, with all the platform-specific signal handlers registered and SEH enabled on Windows, I catch and report a lot of helpful information, most importantly, the file and line number of where the bad thing happened. However, in the callstack, I have noticed that I never actually get the location of any `throw` statements, only where it was caught, i.e. a `catch` block. As you can imagine, if your `try-catch` encompasses a gigantic amount of code, where the exception was caught is not terribly helpful. So, why is that?

And now for the obvious followup question: How do I get the location of `throw` statements into my callstack console dumps?

I will stop anyone who tries to tell me to change all the `throw` statements to custom exceptions with `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros right here. Please refer back to my opening sentence. As such, present uses of `throw` will not be changed.

Comment: You don't. Exceptions don't carry that kind of information unless you put it there yourself.

Comment: you can throw different messages from different places. take a look at ADO programming how they do handle exceptions correctly: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Cubic Yes, I know exceptions do not contain any information unless I put it there - I inferred as much and that is not what I asked. The question at hand is: _Why_ doesn't the output from a `backtrace()` call have the location of the `throw` statement? That seems odd to me. Several people have asked similar questions, but no one has ever said why this is so.

Comment: At least in SEH on Windows, a `throw` statement does not use a `CALL` instruction, so it cannot appear on a dump of a *call*-stack.  When an exception is thrown, the compiled code translate the `throw` into a call to `RaiseException()`, which generates an exception that the OS responds to by walking the handler chain located in the throwing thread's `fs:[0]` register until it finds a match, and then jumps execution to that handler.  See [A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32 Structured Exception Handling](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx)